# How can I loop for 'n' dimensions of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create a method that will sum up the potential items and return that sum from an array. Here are some sample inputs that would be expected:

```java
arraySum(new int[10]); // 10
arraySum(new int[2][5]); // 10
arraySum(new int[5][5][5]); // 125
```

The problem is I can never actually know how many dimensions I am working with. So far, I've found that calling `String.valueOf(array)` on an array returns a string which contains `[` characters for however many dimensions exist in the array:

```java
String.valueOf(new int[10]); // [I@hash_code
String.valueOf(new int[5][2]); // [[I@hash_code
String.valueOf(new int[5][5][5]); // [[[I@hash_code
```

I can use this to find out the exact amount of dimensions that exist for that array by doing `String.valueOf(array).split("\\[").length - 1`. I'm not sure what I can do from this point however.

```
public int arraySum(final Object array) {
    checkArgument(array.getClass().isArray()); // from com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    final int dimensions = String.valueOf(array).split("\\[").length - 1;
    int sum = 0;

    // somehow loop n-times over here to count up

    return sum;
}
```

Normally when iterating on multi-dimensional arrays, you would have multiple loops inside of one another, but in my case, I would need n-loops, which I obviously can't hardcode. What can I do?

Comment: Recursion! In each recursive call, iterate on the next dimension :) Although, I'm not sure how you're going to visualize an n-dimensional array on a 2-d console :P

Comment: That's right! It didn't come to my mind at all, and I've been sitting here for a while trying to think up of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
public static int arraySum(final Object[] array) {
    if(array.length == 0) return 0;
    return array.length * ((array[0] instanceof Object[]) ? arraySum((Object[]) array[0]) : 1);
}
```

You can also overload this method for primitives arrays. Here is how I would do it with minimal code duplication:

```
private static int doArraySum(Object array) {
    if(array == null || !array.getClass().isArray()) return 1;
    int length = Array.getLength(array);
    if(length == 0) return 0;
    return length * doArraySum(Array.get(array, 0));
}

public static int arraySum(Object[] array) {
    return doArraySum(array);
}

public static int arraySum(int[] array) {
    return doArraySum(array);
}

// other primitives
```

---

If the length of the sub-arrays may not be equal, you should use addition instead of multiplication:

```
private static int doArraySum(Object array) {
    if (array == null || !array.getClass().isArray()) return 1;
    return IntStream
            .range(0, Array.getLength(array))
            .map(i -> doArraySum(Array.get(array, i)))
            .sum();
}
```

Example:

```
int[][] array = new int[2][];
array[0] = new int[2];
array[1] = new int[3];
arraySum(array); // 5
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted, even though I didn't implement it exactly the way you did, mainly because you have a ton of pretty neat information that I was able to use to derive my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a for loop to iterate on the dimensions and perform multiplication of the lengths:

```java
public int arraySum(Object array) {
    int count = 1;      // necessary to prevent initial 0 multiplication
    int dim = ...;      // the dimensions of the array

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
        int len = Array.getLength(array);
        count *= len;

        if (len == 0) {
            break; // a length of 0 at any point means no potential items
        }

        array = Array.get(array, 0); // never fails, since len must be greater than 1 by this point
    }
}
```

This gives me the *potential* length, or otherwise the capacity of the array to hold a specific type.

```
arraySum(new int[10]);          // 1 array with 10 ints, capacity 10 * 1 == 10
arraySum(new float[10][2]);     // 2 arrays with 10 floats, capacity of 2 * 10 == 20
arraySum(new CustomType[5][5]); // 5 arrays with 5 custom types, capacity 5 * 5 == 25
```